# How can I search with special characters?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm manager for a project from Vietnam search in SQL. Some thing like this

```
select N'Trên bootrap , click nút setting ko thấy phản ứng' as title into #test
select * from #test where title like N'%Trên%'
select * from #test where title like N'%ứng%'

-------------------
select * from #test where title like N'%ứng%'
```

But today my customer give me some characters like above.

From sql select above you can see:

1. Trên = Trên => it Ok. But
2. ứng <> ứng (because user input from orther computer). I don't know how can solove this situation.

Comment: What database / SQL are you using? e.g. Oracle, MySQL, ...

Comment: @metters: My project include SQL server and Oracle, Posgresql. All of them "ứng <> ứng"

Comment: Whats the datatype of `title` column ?

Comment: nvarchar, character varying

Comment: @HongVanVit . . . This looks like SQL Server code so I added the tag.  You have a large enough rep that you should know how to tag a question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 SELECT * FROM #test WHERE title LIKE "%ứng%" COLLATE utf8mb4_german2_ci
```

`utf8mb4_unicode_ci` would probably work as well.

Comment: @Hong Van Vit, did this help you?